# Strut 2.3.1.2 Unit test, how to remove Spring codependency vs NPE with getContext()

Tags: spring, struts2, actioncontext

I'm just upgrading to Struts 2.3.1.2, and having a few issues with JUnit tests.

My old test code was like this....

```
public class HomeActionTest  {

    @Test
    public void testUserNameErrorMessage() throws Exception {
     HomeAction action = new HomeAction();
     setupMocks(action);
     action.execute();
    }
}
```

The action class's execute method has the code

```
    String text = getText(GLOBAL_SELECT);
```

This causes a NullPointerExeception though in LocalizedTextUtil since it calls...

```
   ActionContext.getContext()
```

Now I could try and do this...

```
  ActionContext.setContext(new ActionContext(new HashMap()));
```

But then I'll get a NullPointerException since the Valuestack from the context is null.
I could go on and on trying to fix these problems, but it seems like a futile task. 
There must be a better way?!?

Well....

I follow the new [Struts 2.3.x.x testing doc](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/struts-2-junit-plugin-tutorial.html)

My struts.xml is wired with spring.

```
 <action name="secure/home" class="homeAction" method="execute">
            <result>home.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">home.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

My Test class

```
public class HomeActionTest extends StrutsSpringTestCase   {

    @Test
    public void testUserNameErrorMessage() throws Exception {
        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/secure/home");

        // setup the session
        Map<String, Object> session = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
        ActionContext actionContext = proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext();  
        actionContext.setSession(session);  

        HomeAction homeAction = (HomeAction) proxy.getAction();

        proxy.execute();
    }
}
```

But this now means I get a fully populated Spring injected Action class! 
Most people would saying "YEA!!!" at this point.

My problem is that this isn't a UNIT test class, its now making calls all the way down to the DB layer since that's how its wired for run-time.

So here is my question, I know I've taken a while to get to it, **is it possible to get an Action class that has access to resources it needs (for method calls such as getText()), but is not all Spring wired up?**

For the moment I'm tempted to go the refection route to remove all methods that match setServicexxxx on my action, at least then I'd get a NullPointerException on running the test and I can mock out that service, but that's just wrong. I want my tests to be FAST, not spend 2 seconds starting up the Spring context.

How did Struts2.3 end up with a Base test class that doesn't follow the mantra of what a Unit test is?

This was all fine in Struts 2.0.9 (xwork-2.0.3.jar).

What am I missing?

Comment: ... An action *should* be "all wired up" in a unit test--what it's wired *with* is what you're missing--you don't have a test context.

Comment: Hi Dave, you are correct I don't have a test-context, but I dont want to duplicate my main context.

In the end I've settled with rewiring my Action classes with mocks, and taking the hit of spring starting up. Not a big hit, but at the time it annoyed me that my tests took a few seconds longer.

If a mod wants to remove this question they can, I know it doesn't really have a set 'Answer' and may not be that useful to others.

Comment: I take back what I said about removing this question. The post by Alban is great for those that want to mock out the Action classes ApplicationContext

Comment: You must mean `ActionContext`, because the mocking shown has zero to do with Spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should indeed keep your unit test as fast as possible (otherwise, no TDD). So you should do the minimum struts setup: (I'm using mockito and I have this code in a static block, full code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2948345))

```
ActionContext actionContext = mock(ActionContext.class);
ServletContext servletContext = mock(ServletContext.class);
when(actionContext.getLocale()).thenReturn(Locale.FRENCH);
ValueStack valueStack = mock(ValueStack.class);
Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String,Object>();
Container container = mock(Container.class);
XWorkConverter conv = mock(XWorkConverter.class);
when(container.getInstance(XWorkConverter.class)).thenReturn(conv);
when(conv.convertValue(any(Map.class), any(Object.class), any(Class.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        log.info(invocation.getArguments()[1].toString());
        return "VALUE";
    }

});
context.put(ActionContext.CONTAINER, container);
when(valueStack.getContext()).thenReturn(context);
when(actionContext.getValueStack()).thenReturn(valueStack);
ServletActionContext.setContext(actionContext);
ServletActionContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
```

Comment: Thanks Alban, that mocking is great!