# How to test struts 2.0.x applications

Tags: java, unit-testing, struts2, junit

How do we test action classes of Applications written in 2.0.x version?

I read through [this link](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/junit-plugin.html) and found out that, struts-junit plugin is only available for struts 2.1.1 or later.

My application is written using struts 2.0.11 and I don't think upgrading the version is easy in my project.

How do we unit test Action classes,given these limitations ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any special aspects of your action classes that you would like to test?

As long as your action classes are written as POJOs, you can test them as ordinary Java classes using any testing framework of your choice.

**EDIT:** Give a try [this custom class](http://depressedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2007/06/18/unit-testing-struts-2-actions-spring-junit/) which extends JUnit's `TestCase` class. You will need dependency to [org.springframework: spring-mock](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-mock).

Comment: It has http request and response objects. It can't be tested as POJOs

Comment: you say it uses"http request and response objects", couldn't you inject these into your action? You would then just mock them using mockito for example. @jilt3d advices to test them as POJO. Don't add any other dependency, keep your tests simple.

Comment: Also checkout this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756591/strut-2-3-1-2-unit-test-how-to-remove-spring-codependency-vs-npe-with-getcontex/11051902#11051902): It is about setting up struts2 ServletContext to avoid some issues we have when junit-testing struts2 actions as POJO

Comment: @VinothKumar The objects an instance has isn't related to whether or not it's a POJO, and (essentially) anything can be mocked or stubbed. You can also integration test if your classes aren't designed to be testable and the ROI isn't worth it.